# Python get max price sum 3 top records

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have a table where data like :

```
Id            price             date         user_id    type  match_id
_____________________________________________________________________

1            120              2021-03-05     1        credit    1
2            120              2021-03-05     1        credit    1
3            120              2021-03-08     2        credit    2
4            120              2017-06-20     3        credit    2
5            140              2017-06-20     4        debit     2
6            120              2017-06-20     1        credit    2
8            120              2021-03-09     2        credit    1
9            130              2017-06-20     2        credit    1
10           120              2021-03-05     1        debit     2
11           160              2021-03-05     5        debit     1
12           210              2021-03-05     5        credit    1
```

what i actually want is i want distinct user according to userid and created_at between 2021-03-05 to 2021-03-11 with type credit 3 top price users  with price sum .

3 top user which have max price sum according to this filter. i am stuck here can anyone please help me related this ??

Model i have:

```
class PriceLog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="price_log")
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=(
            ('credit', 'Credit'),
            ('debit', 'Debit')
        ),
    )
    price = models.IntegerField()
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='price_logs', null=True, default=None)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'price_logs'
```

Comment: Please share your *model*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i have update my question with model now ..

Answer (score 0):

You can work with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Sum

User.objects.filter(
    price_log__created_at__range=('2021-03-05', '2021-03-11'),
    price_log__type='credit'
).annotate(
    max_price=Sum('price_log__price')
).order_by('-max_price')[:3]
```

This is a `QuerySet` that will contain (at most) three `User`s with the largest prices for the given time range and with `credit` as type. The `User` objects that arise from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.max_price` with that maximum price.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.

Comment: The filter is on the user. So the annotation won't use the filter if I am correct (as long as the user has one matching pricelog the annotation would use all of them)?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: it will, you can filter the related models that will be used for aggregation, since this acts as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: What I mean is the filter will only filter out users that have at least one matching price log. After which the annotation would use all of the users price log if I understand the ORM correctly?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: see for example here where we count the number of books that start with Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#filter-and-exclude

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: no that is a popular misconception of how the Django ORM works. It performs a the LEFT OUTER JOIN only once, so we perform the filtering on the annotation aggregate as well, as is explained in the linked documentation.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it is not working it is returning the error cos user table not have field price_log

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: for example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses) they use `Publisher.objects.filter(book__rating__gt=3.0).annotate(num_books=Count('book'))` to obtain the number of books with a rating > 3..

Comment: @Pankhuri: that is the relation doe to the `related_name='price_log'`. Are you sure that is the correct name?

Comment: @Pankhuri: well exactly *what* is the error?

Comment: Your answer has `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`. Perhaps the issue is that @Pankhuri has a custom user model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry my bad .. but it is displaying on user object not price total

Comment: @Pankhuri: sorry I misunderstood, you need to replace `Max` with `Sum`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i did the same but in result i am getting like <QuerySet [<User: Data>, <User: pankhuri>, <User: Cosmo>]>

Comment: @Pankhuri: sure, and these `User`s have an attribute `.max_price` that is the sum of the credit `PriceLog`s in that period. The queryset thus contains the top 3 users, and you can even inspect the sum of the credits. So it is not clear to me what is still missing?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem total credit count,debit count and no of total match count i am not getting in queryset..

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it is returning me the user but price logs info is not there like their total credit and debit count and their match count.

Comment: @Pankhuri: you can inspect it with a `myuser` from the queryset, and see `myuser.price_log.all()` which is a queryset of all related logs, and then filter down, aggregate, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem actually this is not my question about i aslo want the details like credit,debit count